# Bootstrap/JS functionality to display certain tab info

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently working on a global search page. A user puts in a search, All results are displayed. But then I want the user to be able to click on certain tabs to display the results as well. It is currently bootstrapped. The `all` tabs is the only one that is currently working because it is the class is set to `active`. The `all` tab also wraps the other tabs. I will try to give an example if I wanted to display `Events`

I first have the nav tab section set like this...

```html
<div class="search-tab">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#all">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#events_tab">Events</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#appointments_tab">Appointment</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#phonecalls_tab">Phone Calls</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#vendors_tab">Vendors</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then the data I want to retrieve is wrapped inside the `all` div tab like the `events_tab` here.

```html
<div id="all" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <div class="list-panel table-sort" id="events_tab">
    this will display the events related to the search...
  </div>
</div>
```

I am fairly new to using bootstrap. Any advice/tips would be a huge help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its a little unclear as to whether you want All to have nested tabs or not. However, regarding Bootstraps tab HTML markup pattern, you'll want to wrap your `.tab-pane` in a `.tab-content` wrapper. Also, be sure you're including jQuery as well as Bootstraps JS bundle (after jQuery) so the `data-` attributes can be used.

**Updated HTML for non-nested tabs and tab panes**

```
<div class="search-tab">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#all">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#events_tab">Events</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#appointments_tab">Appointment</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#phonecalls_tab">Phone Calls</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#vendors_tab">Vendors</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class='tab-content'>
  <div id="all" class="tab-pane fade show active">
    all area
  </div> 
  <div id='events_tab' class='tab-pane fade'>
    events area
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle showing the updated markup without nested tabs:
https://jsfiddle.net/onuj90dz/

If you're wanting to show the search results in addition to these other categories (events, appointments, calls, vendors), you could put the results in a non-`tab` container. A crude example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/onuj90dz/1/

Comment: Ah thank you so much for the help! A lot better now. One issue that I am trying to figure out is that if my search result returns an event, I do see it in the events tab. But if I click on appointments after that, it still brings the event data to that tab. So I am trying to figure out how to clear that out.